# Ethernet shield can't connect server with keep alive connection

Tags: arduino, http-headers, connection, ethernet

I want to use Ethernet shield to send/get data from my Apche server (localhost).

```
Ethernet(or Esp8266) ======(request.php by post method)==>>> server 
Ethernet(or Esp8266) <<<=====(respond header and data)==== server
```

i send header to server to get data.

In my header:
If i use ***connection: close***. This way seems ok.
 But when i use ***connection: keep-alive***. it can't connect or get any data **till connection time out**.
This is my header and way to send my data to server:

```
String httpRequest(String data){
   String result="";
   if(client.connect(server, 80)){
    Serial.println("connected");

    client.println("POST /pihome1/getStatus.php HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: localhost");
    client.println("Accept: *" "/" "*");
    client.println("Content-Length: " + String(data.length()));
    client.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    client.println("Connection: keep-alive");
    client.println();
    client.print(data);
  }
  else {
    //if you didn't get a connection to the server:
    Serial.println("connection failed");
  }
//Reading data
    unsigned long start = millis();
    int timeout = 2000;
    while (millis() - start < timeout){ 
      while (client.available()) {
        char c = client.read();
        result += c;
      }  
    }
  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("disconnecting.");
    client.flush();
    client.stop();
  }
   return result;
}
```

After the first success it can't connect till time out connect.

```
========Request to server=========
connected
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 04 Oct 2015 08:03:46 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.16
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.16
Content-Length: 10
Keep-Alive: timeout=50, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html



1&1eos
========End of request=========
========Request to server=========
connection failed

========End of request========
```

Please tell me what problems?

Comment: Have you done a tcpdump to see what happen on the network ? Try HTTP/1.1 instead of 1.0. Perhaps client.print don't flush the data on the network, check your lib, `flush` can help

Comment: I tried HTTP1.1 and use : client.flush();
    client.stop();. But it't not working.

Comment: Have you tried a tcpdump to see what happen on the network ?

Comment: With keep alive connection. Browser usually send back server with a **cookie**. Is it right Orel? Server knows that "the connection is connected before"

Comment: Cookie has nothing to do with your case.
You really need to do a tcpdump to see what happen. On basic http, server closes the connection after it answer. With keep-alive flag, the server doesn't close the connection and wait for other query.

Comment: i use **wireshark** to capture this connection. I don't have many knowledge about Network. the My **TCP protocol** has problems. I think I just work on application layer. but I don't know way to work with the layer has **TCP protocol**.

I only read some information from **wireshark**, i don't know the problem exactly.  Could you tell me what the problem?? This is my captured file: 
http://1drv.ms/1KYSzOo

Comment: You can add a filter on port 80, on capture option > capture Filter just add `port 80`. I have looked you file,  using `tcp.port == 80` in the Filter. There is two POST. The connection of the first POST is  maintained opened for 50s, Your server has answered in packet 57, the arduino acked it on packet 58 and the server has closed the connection on packet 129, after 50s. There is no network problem, the connection is kept alive.

Comment: Is this problem: **client.connect(server, 80)**? The Ethernet Shield try to create new connection?? My Ethernet shield tries to get data after the first http success. but It can't. in wireshark. After every **connection failed** in wireshark display `No valid function.....` in info

Comment: Can you show the code reading the answer ? As previously said, the connect and the POST are correctly done

Comment: Must I program TCP for Ethernet Shield??

Comment: You should test if you are connected before open a new connection `if(client.connect(server, 80)){` => `if (client.connected() || client.connect(server, 80)){`

Comment: Thank you Orel. I will try and tell you what happen.

Comment: Thank you Ôrel. It works. 
By the way, I want to ask you the same  function "client.connected()" on **Esp8266**? Could you tell me?

Comment: That function  is "AT+CIPSTART" .....It returns Already connect